# Authentication Options for ADFS 3.0 and NetCore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, adfs3.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I oddly do not find any documentation around how to setup ASP.NET CORE with ADFS 3.0, but enough about other providers. How can I set this up in ASP.NET CORE, as my company only uses ADFS 3.0 as SSO solution.

I've seen a (paid) solution called [Auth0](https://auth0.com/authenticate/aspnet-core/ws-fed), but I first want to try without any 3rd party paid options.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm working on a .Net Core 2.0 MVC project and am also attempting to use ADFS 3.0.

Comment: @rag9 Did you find a solution to this? I am in the same position haha